# Unable to create Bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-bean

this is my declaration of the bean

```
@Bean
public Set<Long> getIds(){
return new HashSet<Long>();
}
```

and this is how i use and autowired it.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("getIds")
private Set<Long> listIds;
```

somehow it just wont create the bean and eventually raise a there is no qualifying bean. but if I change the datatype to String it works just fine. I wonder what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Put a log statement in the `@Bean` method. Does that get logged?

Comment: nope, but i tried creating a constructor in my configuration class and it logged it. and somehow missed creating the bean like its trying to autowire first instead of creating the bean.

Comment: Take a look at the duplicate. You won't be able to inject beans of type `Collection`  with `@Autowired`. You'll want to use `@Resource` and set its `name`.

Comment: Yes @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry i kind of missed it. It solved the problem. thanks alot!